# Mounting a Windows 10 Base Filesystem as Read-Only?

Tags: windows, boot, vhd, dism

I'm trying to create a Windows volume where the base image is mounted as read-only to prevent corruption after a sudden power loss.

Here is what I've attempted so far:

I've created a VHD file from the WIM on the target machine. I added this VHD to Windows Boot Manager, but the VHD still retains changes made by a user after powering off. I've tried using the /ReadOnly flag in DISM but that didn't seem to change the behavior of the VHD.

I've tossed around the idea of trying to mount the VHD as read only from the PE environment if I can't create a read only base image directly with Windows Boot Manager or using virtualization with Linux and Qemu to create a template where a new machine is initialized at each boot, but both of these solutions leave me feeling like I'm overcomplicating things.

I'm open to any ideas there might be to accomplish this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to create a differencing disk with my main VHD as the parent. I wrote some batch scripts to create a new differencing disk at startup, which I then set as the primary boot option in the Windows boot manager, and removed the old differencing disk from the Windows boot manager. This left me with a clean image on every boot.

Answer (score 0):

- Use *diskpart* to [make the *volume* read-only](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-write-protect-an-external-hard-drive/cf7ed39c-d949-4f42-a5be-ea7200890201) (*Caveat:* there are typos in that link.):

  - Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *cmd*, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get an elevated CMD prompt.
  - Type *diskpart* and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
  - Type *list volume* and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
  - Type *sel vol #* and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, where # is the number of the partition to write-protect.
  - Type *attr vol set readonly* and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to make that volume read-only.
  - Type *attr vol* and<kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm that it is read-only.
  - To later clear that restriction, do as above and type *attr vol clear readonly*; use *attr vol* to confirm.
  - Type *exit* and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to leave *diskpart*
- Alternatively, put the OS and files on write-protected media, e.g., DVD or SD card with write-protect switch.

Comment: Thank you very much! This would definitely make the VHD read-only, which is what I proposed, and it's my fault for not explaining better what I was looking for. The overall goal was to be able to have a VHD that Windows would boot from that would discard any changes after reboot, preventing corruption on a sudden power loss. I ended up making this work with a differencing disk and some batch scripting.